# Can I generate an AzureAD B2C password reset URL via GraphAPI?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm building an application for a client where we are using AzureAD B2C for user authentication, and out account creation flow looks like the following,

1. User enters their account details, other than password.
2. These details are sent off to Azure with a randomly generated password to create the account.
3. The user authenticates their email address using a 3rd party OTP solution, this is the clients own OTP solution, not Azure (This is a requirement and cannot change)
4. The user then is taken to a page to create their password for the account rather than the randomly generated one.

Essentially, I'm unsure how we can redirect from the 3rd party email verification page to a password reset page without forcing the user to login and then reset their password. I also cannot use a password reset GraphAPI call as the client does not want to handle any credentials on our services and wants to keep all calls containing credentials within AzureAD

The solution I thought of can I request a password reset through GraphAPI and just redirect the user to the URL provided by Graph?

If there is a better solution than the one I suggeseted please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "magic link", i.e., the user gets an email with a link inside. The user clicks the link, and it sends a JWT to authenticate the flow that contains the user's email. Then, the user can reset that email address's password via the B2C password reset screen.

Samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-email) and [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link).

Write-ups [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-jwt-to-invoke-an-azure-ad-b2c-flow-using-id-token-hint-13752ee6d9df) and [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/hosting-the-id-token-hint-well-known-endpoint-in-azure-ad-b2c-itself-1c27be147613).

Comment: Issue with this is that the client doesn’t want that flow, they want it all seamless. The client wants it so that as soon as they’ve verified their email using the 3rd party OTP service, the user is taken to an azure password reset page. Still not sure if what they’re looking for is even doable